# Compile c code in c# project

Tags: c#, .net, c

I want to compile c code (check syntax) inside c# project
or i want to know how to use GCC compiler in c# application

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5.aspx) will let you run any application including GCC (or any other compiler/make utility) and pass arguments.

```
Process.Start("gcc.exe", "my.c");
```

You probably need more command line options than just file name (i.e. output/include folder locations) and may need to specify path to compiler if it is not already available in the PATH environment variable.

Comment: @EslamTotti - If you just need to verify a piece of code - save it to file ([Path.GetTempFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename.aspx) ) and compile. If you need dynamic syntax checking or syntax checking for partial code - you need much more integrated approach and I don't think plain GCC will be enough.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov i want to download gcc.exe and where i put this file in my project?

Comment: @EslamTotti this search query should get you started http://www.bing.com/search?q=gcc+compiler, if you hit roadblocks - ask new question.